# Hikari timeout oracle springboot

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, oracle, conexão, pooling

Olá, estou tentando configurar um pool de conexões manualmente com o Hikari.
Precisarei fazer manual porque a aplicação terá suas configurações dinâmicas para conexão com os bancos e schemas/Sid.

Como estou configurando as conexões:

```java
    HikariConfig configHikari = new HikariConfig();
    configHikari.setUsername("username");
    configHikari.setPassword("password");
    configHikari.setJdbcUrl("url");
    configHikari.setDriverClassName("driver");
    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(configHikari);
```

Estou conseguindo usar as conexões, porém passado algum tempo, tenho o seguinte erro abaixo:

```java
16:31:44.044  WARN          com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@5111dd1a (IO Error: Invalid Operation, NOT Connected). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
16:31:49.049  WARN          com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@703110b7 (IO Error: Invalid Operation, NOT Connected). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
16:31:54.054  WARN          com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@555f60aa (IO Error: Invalid Operation, NOT Connected). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.

org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30170ms.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82)
```

Já tentei aumentar o max-life-time do hikari, mais depois com um tempo tenho o mesmo erro.

```java
 configHikari.setMaxLifetime(600000);
```

O que preciso configurar para que a conexão se reconecte? existe algum max-life-time infinito? e é saudável ter um max-life-time muito grande?
Ainda não testei nos outros bancos para perceber se estou tendo o mesmo erro, por enquanto testei apenas no oracle e já obtive este problema.

E no momento tenho que ficar restartando a aplicação quando esse tempo vence.

Comment: Relacionada (SOen): https://stackoverflow.com/q/28180562/2241463

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pelo que notei seu banco é oracle.

Quando é gerado esse problema, ele está relacionado ao maxTimeLife e o wait_timeout do banco de dados.

O WARN gerado é porque o maxTimeLife está alto (você mesmo disse que está tentando colocar um valor alto) e está maior que o wait_timeout do banco de dados.

Veja o que diz a [documentação](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP):

> This property controls the maximum lifetime of a connection in the pool. An in-use connection will never be retired, only when it is closed will it then be removed. On a connection-by-connection basis, minor negative attenuation is applied to avoid mass-extinction in the pool. **We strongly recommend setting this value, and it should be several seconds shorter than any database or infrastructure imposed connection time limit.** A value of 0 indicates no maximum lifetime (infinite lifetime), subject of course to the idleTimeout setting. The minimum allowed value is 30000ms (30 seconds). Default: 1800000 (30 minutes)

Pelo que pesquisei, por padrão o Oracle não tem setado um valor para o wait_timeout, o que achei estranho. Não tem um ponto de configuração para isso.

Mas tem um dado associado ao profile do usuário do banco, que pode influenciar isso. É o parâmtero *IDLE_TIME*.

Baseado [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42021994/how-to-check-what-current-idle-time-is-set-at-in-oracle/42022379#42022379) você consegue consultar isso com:

```
SELECT p.limit
FROM dba_profiles p, dba_users u
WHERE p.resource_name = 'IDLE_TIME' and p.profile = u.profile and u.username = '...';
```

Veja se isso retorna algo.

Pelo que entendo, se o `maxLifeTime` estiver menor que o parâmetro correto do banco, quando esse tempo for atingido de forma natural o Hiraki recria conexões de forma natural.

Espero ter contribuído, mesmo sentindo que ajudei pouco.

Comment: deu certinho! resolvi colocando `spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=30000` para as config do spring e `configHikari.setMaxLifetime(30000)` para as minhas conexões dinâmicas. Vlw